# What if you have 2 identical routes in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, routes

I am trying to understand how Symfony 5 routing works.

What will happen if in my project I have 2 different controllers with the same route name?

For example, in Controller1.php:

```
/**
 * @Route("/publisher/notification_update/")
 */
```

And in Controller2.php:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/publisher/notification_update/")
 */
```

Then from somewhere inside a twig, I have a form that calls this route as follows:

```
<form name="notification" id="notification{{message.notification_id}}"  
        action="/publisher/notification_update/" style="display:none"
        method="post">
        <input hidden class="hiddenNotificationsForUser" type="text" id="{{message.notification_id}}"
            value="{{message.message}}" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

What will happen in this case? Will there be an error, or will it go to the first route it finds alphabetically?

Comment: I guess you could try it out and see what happens ;)
To spoil the fun of finding out: you won't get an error and the first match (Controller1) is used.

Comment: this might be useful too: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter

Comment: And the routes are not matched alphabetically but rather in the order they are defined with an optional priority.  bin/console debug:router will show you defined routes and they order they match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing this scenario with Symfony 5 on a LEMP server in DigitalOcean, I found out that there is no error or warning message.

Symfony picked the route specified in Controller1.php:

```
/**
* @Route("/publisher/notification_update/")
*/
```

This, however, is a bad thing because having the situation I described combined with a large code base can lead to a very hard to identify bug.
You may never reach the route that you need even if everything is correct with it's contents.

Comment: The router allows [ordering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter) so that multiple routes may be allowed to have the pattern. There is no checker to determine a specific route pattern and properties isn't already defined (this has happened to me). This seems appropriate to me, and probably indicates a domain organization smell more than a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

In symfony 5 I have used `#[Route(['/login', 'admin/login'], name: 'app_user_login')]` for route two url paths for single controller action